# Angular 6 How to add holidays to kendo UI scheduler?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

How can I add holidays in Kendo UI scheduler in Angular 6?

Actually, I have a JSON array with holidays and on a holiday the user should not be able to add events and also the background color for holidays should be changed.

EDITED : And how could be changed bg-color of weekend days?

Answer (score 1):

The following example demonstrates how to use the events to prevent the user from editing the Scheduler events based on some condition [link](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/scheduler/editing/restrictions/)

Based on that you can add a "holiday event" and then restrict this event from editing, also you can set any background color for this event.

Comment: tnx but how could change bg color for every day (not just event but rather the day's slot), that's a holiday.  or how to hide "remove icon" from the holiday's event.